# Finding a key in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, recursion

I have the following json:

```
let object = {
"statusCode": 200,
"body": [{
        "id": "3",
        "externalId": "billgates",
        "status": "active",
        "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "firstName": "yehu",
        "lastName": "da",
        "email": "bg@g.com"
    }
],
"headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "189",
    "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
    "date": "<<Masked>>",
    "connection": "close"
},
"request": {
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "mysite",
        "port": "4202",
        "hostname": "mysite",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?username=billgates",
        "query": "username=billgates",
        "pathname": "/v1/users",
        "path": "/v1/users?username=billgates",
        "href": "http://mysite"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-length": 2
    }
}
```

}

i wrote a function that gets a key and a value and if key with that value found in json returns true otherwise false, here is the function:

```
let key = "externalId";
let value = "bilgates"
let findValue = function findValue(obj, key, value) {
            for(let localKey in obj){
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty(localKey)){
                    if(localKey === key){
                        res = obj[localKey] === value;
                        return res;
                    }
                    else{
                        let val = obj[localKey];
                        findValue(val, key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 let res = findValue(object, key, value)
 console.log(res);
```

after running the function in VS Code (node.js) I get the following error:

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

after debugging the function, I could not found the problem. It seems that after some point, localKey will be always zero and obj[localKey] will be always 3.

Comment: hint ... it's `"id": "3",` that is causing the problem (you need to check if `obj[localKey]` is an actual OBJECT before recursing ...you'll also need to recurse PROPERLY - because unless the key is found in the top level, you'll always get undefined once you fix your infinite recursion

Comment: Note that if you're dealing with a plain object without a meaningful internal prototype, the `hasOwnProperty` check is superfluous. (or just use `Object.keys`/`entries` instead, which only iterate over properties directly on the object)

Comment: quickest *fix* for your code https://pastebin.com/8YQb4mQ3 - but I wouldn't do it this way at all

Comment: @Bravo why you wouldn't do it this way. whats wrong with it?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know why I said that :p I quickly tried other ways and realised the error of that part of the statement :

Answer (score 0):

Though a different solution, still you can try below approach

```js
let object = {
"statusCode": 200,
"body": [{
        "id": "3",
        "externalId": "billgates",
        "status": "active",
        "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "firstName": "yehu",
        "lastName": "da",
        "email": "bg@g.com"
    }
],
"headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "189",
    "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
    "date": "<<Masked>>",
    "connection": "close"
},
"request": {
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "mysite",
        "port": "4202",
        "hostname": "mysite",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?username=billgates",
        "query": "username=billgates",
        "pathname": "/v1/users",
        "path": "/v1/users?username=billgates",
        "href": "http://mysite"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-length": 2
    }
}
}

function findValue(obj, k, v) {
  let res = false

  if(!obj || typeof obj != "object") return false

  if (obj[k] == v) return true
  else {
 for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
          if(Array.isArray(value)) { res = res || value.some(d => findValue(d, k, v)) }
   if(typeof value == "object") { res = res || findValue(value, k, v) }
    }
  }
  return res
}

console.log(findValue(object, 'externalId', 'billgates'))

console.log(findValue(object, 'lastName', 'da'))

console.log(findValue(object, 'x-powered-by', 'Express'))

console.log(findValue(object, 'externalId', 'Nitish'))
```